# Differentiable function on an interval containing 0

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

So I am looking to see if my solution is correct. This is an exercise from Abbott's second edition of Understanding Analysis.

Exercise:

Let f be differentiable on an interval $A$ containing zero, and assume $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ with $(x_n)→0$ and $x_n \neq 0$.

(a) If $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n∈N$, show $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$.

(b) Add the assumption that f is twice-differentiable at zero and show that $f''(0) = 0$ as well.

My solution:

Here we let $(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ and $x_n  \neq 0$

(a) Since $f$ is a continuous function on $A$. So $f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ but $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n \in N$. Therefore $f(0) = 0$.

Now $f'(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} ({f(x)- f(0)})/x = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)/x$. As the function is differentiable on $A$, $f'(0)$ exists. Therefore $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)/x = \lim_{x_{n} \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n})/x_{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0/x_{n} = 0$. So we have $f'(0)=0$.

(b) If $f$ is twice differentiable then

$f''(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} ({f'(x)- f'(0)})/x = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x)/x$. The limit exists by our assumption, so for any sequence $(y_n) \neq 0$ and $(y_n) \rightarrow 0$ we must have

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f'(y_n)/y_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} f'(x)/x$. Now $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f'(x_n)/x_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0/x_n = 0$. Therefore $f''(0)=0$.

Comment: Why did you decide that $f'(x_n)=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: And a hint for when you give up on $f'(x_n)=0$.  Maybe you can find some other sequence of points, between the $x_n$ points  so that $f'(\xi_n)=0$.

Comment: sorry I forgot to write that f(x_n) implies f(0). Im not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: BrianO answered it here.  You were trying to answer (b) using only the fact that $f(0)=0$,  $f'(0)=0$, $f (x_n)=0$ and $x_n\to 0$ and $f$ has two derivatives at $0$.  That's not much information to determine that $f''(0)=0$.  Had that been true then you wouldn't need the hypothesis that $f$ is "differentiable on an interval."  That phrase in your studies should always set off alarm bells repeating   "don't forget the mean-value theorem" over and over.  It is the standard tool for using information about the derivative to conclude something about a function,

Answer (score 6):

It's all good except your last paragraph. You don't know that $f'(x_n) = 0$, so you can't rewrite $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f'(x_n)/x_n$ as $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}0/x_n$. However, you can argue as follows:

Without loss of generality we can assume that for all $n$, $x_n\ne x_{n+1}$, and all $x_n$ are negative or all are positive. This is possible because either $\{n\in \mathbb{N} \mid x_n \gt 0\}$ or $\{n\in \mathbb{N} \mid x_n \gt 0\}$ is infinite. If $(x_n)$ doesn't have these properties, in any case it has a subsequence that does and we can use that.

For each $n$, $f(x_n) = f(x_{n+1}) = 0$, so by the mean value theorem there is $y_n$ between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ such that
$$
f'(y_n) = \frac {f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n)} {x_{n+1} - x_n} = \frac 0 {x_{n+1} - x_n} = 0.
$$
Clearly, $(y_n)\to 0$, and for all $n, y_n \ne 0$.

Because $f''$ exists at $0$,
$$f''(0) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f'(y_n)}{y_n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac 0{y_n} = 0.
$$

Comment: I know this is late, but you also have to ensure $y_n \neq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in order that $(y_n) \subseteq A \setminus \{0\}$ according to the sequential limit criterion. As it stands now, it could very well be that $y_n = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (or even for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$). This can be fixed by noting that either $\{n \colon x_n < 0\}$ or $\{n \colon x_n > 0\}$ is infinite, and constructing a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ accordingly so that $0 < x_{n_{k + 1}} < y_k < x_{n_k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ .

Comment: @Mason just saw your comment, addressed that. Thanks.